# What is average cover bonus?

Tags: xcom-2

Maybe it was in a tip but I must've missed it.  At the end of each mission there is a few stats that pop up, the last one is "Average Cover Bonus".  What exactly does this % mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: It's the average amount of defense your units were receiving from cover at the end of each turn.**

At the end of each of your turns, the game records how many living soldiers you have, and what type of cover each of your units is in (none, low/half, or standing/full). These are added and stored as `CoverCount` and `CoverTotal` respectively. For `CoverTotal`, each type counts as follows:

- No cover - 0
- Low/half cover - 1
- Standing/full cover - 2

At the end of the mission there's a fairly simple calculation:

`CoverPercentage = CoverTotal * 20 / CoverCount`

This represents the fact that low cover adds 20 defense, and high cover adds 40.

Note that `CoverTotal` is added to based on the best possible cover for your soldier. Your soldier can be flanked by 6 aliens, but as long as they're standing next to a full cover tile, they're going to count as full cover for the purposes of this calculation.

Comment: Huh, seems kind of a useless statistic to me.  Would be more interesting to show what the average coverage % of the enemies where when they died, or what my average coverage % were only if they were fired at.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure why they picked that particular statistic to show. I only looked briefly but it seems like they are recording the first stat you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe they felt like the tutorial doesn't hammer in the point "stay in cover" as well as the one from the first part, so they felt players need an additional pointer to learn to do that.

Comment: That sucks. I was hoping this would be the average cover bonus of enemies that you shot at, since that would actually be instructive. Or, at least, the average cover bonus of your troops when they were shot at.